# How to create custom redirect url to replace existing in adminize plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I am figuring how to redirect the url.
Via Inspect Element in Mozilla, I found out the link as below:

```
<a id="mw_title" href="http://yourdomain.com" title="My Site Title" target="_blank">My Workbook</a>
```

Is there a function that i can write in the child theme to overwrite the existing and redirect it to

http://yourdomain.com/example

and open in same page?

I am using wordpress with child theme and the plugin is adminimize and beginner on this.

Thanks guys and looking forward for your advise.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect in php is done by

```
header("Location: yourside.php");
```

so if you can edit the code called on http://yourdomain.com you can add the line

```
header("Location: http://yourdomain.com/example.php");
```

or something like that.

Comment: Hi derHugo, thanks for your speedy reply. i am beginner and still learning on php. Could you guide me in full code?

Comment: I can't guide you in full code since you didn't offer any code in your request. Anyway I tried to update my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks derHugo for your prompt respond. I figure out and idea and will share more about it below

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called .htaccess in the doc root (web/httpdocs or www folder).

Copy the code below and save it in .htaccess file to redirect http://yourdomain.com to http://yourdomain.com/example

```
Redirect 302 / http://yourdomain.com/example
```

Note: Test it with `302` status, if everything was ok and redirection worked fine, then change it to `301`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys !

You guys are awesome and supportive with prompt respond :)

I am using a wordpress plugin ( Adminimize ), I would like to hide all wordpress related items and restrict menus in admin dashboard toolbar.

12 hours ago I read and follow their advice and code one by one to hide all related wp and menu in admin dashboard. As i am a beginner, i realize that it was quite risky to do so.

Therefore I install that plugin, what i did a moment ago is:

I enable Dashboard and disable Admin Bar Back End Options, then i added a custom code into my php as below

```
// add custom menu in wp menu
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'custom_wp_toolbar_link', 999 );

function custom_wp_toolbar_link( $wp_admin_bar ) {
    if( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ){

        $args = array(
            'id' => 'myworkbook',
            'title' => '<span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">'.__( 'Back To Homepage', 'some-textdomain' ).'</span>',
            'href' => 'http://yourdomain.com/my-workbook/',
            'meta' => array(
                'target' => '_self',
                'class' => 'myworkbook',
                'title' => 'My Workbook'
            )
        );
        $wp_admin_bar->add_node($args);

    }
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_wp_toolbar_css_admin' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_wp_toolbar_css_admin' );

function custom_wp_toolbar_css_admin() {
    if( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ){
        wp_register_style( 'add_custom_wp_toolbar_css', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'custom-wp-toolbar-link.css','','', 'screen' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'add_custom_wp_toolbar_css' );
    }
}
```

This is how it looks

https://prnt.sc/fkzdr3

It works like a charm ! Please advise shall there anything to improve , passion to learn more.

TQ all !!